# How to use RequestHeader value in a Get mapping Request rather than using PathVariable in spring boot to fetch a data using findById?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my Spring boot project, I have created a Table named **"Doctor"**. To fetch Doctors data by their Id I have created one Repository interface and one controller class.

Here's the code of my **DoctorRepository** which extends **JpaRepository**:

```
@Repository
public interface DoctorRepository extends JpaRepository<Doctor, Long> {
}
```

And here's the code of my **DoctorController** class-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DoctorController {

    @Autowired
    private DoctorRepository doctorRepository;


    @GetMapping("/doctors/{id}")
    public Doctor getDoctorById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long doctorId) {
        return doctorRepository.findById(doctorId).orElseThrow(()-> new ResourceNotFoundException("","","doctor id "+doctorId+" not found"));
    }


}
```

**Now, the thing is---**

For experiment, I want to send this **doctorId** through the **RequestHeader** rather using **pathVariables**.

Here's a solution I have tried -

```
@GetMapping("/doctors")
public Doctor getDoctorById(@RequestHeader("id") Long doctorId) {
    return doctorRepository.findById(doctorId).orElseThrow(()-> new ResourceNotFoundException("","","doctor id "+doctorId+" not found"));
    }
```

But this solution didn't work for me. So, I need a solution to solve this issue where I can simply send the **doctorId** in the **RequestHeader**.

Comment: What does it mean.. it does not work for you? You get 400? or NPE and 500?

Comment: This is not a good approach, but it should work. Note also that you can simply do `@RequestHeader("id") Doctor doctor`.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you provided is working.

Here is an example of how to prepare and send a request to the service using `curl`:

```
curl -H "id: 10" http://localhost:8080/api/doctors
```

Then `getDoctorById` successfully accepted `doctorId` with the value of 10.